# Page Redirect 301 using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect **/event/path1/{id}/{some_name}** to **/event/path2/{id}**,

I want to redirect old page to the new one and remove the last segment of the url,

I have done with this but not removing the last segment of the url, this is what .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^event/path1/(.*) /event/path2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.*` in your regex that matches everything after `/event/path1/` thus resulting in wrong target URL.

You may use:

```
RewriteRule ^event/path1/([^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ /event/path2/$1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Here `[^/]+` will match 1 or more of any non-slash character.

`?` at the end of the target will strip off any previous query string.

Comment: this solves my problem, how about removing the query string, like in the new page there is a query string but I want to remove it, ```/event/path2?data=data_value```

Comment: So your old URI is `/event/path1/{id}/{some_name}` or just `/event/path1?data=data_value` ?

Comment: this is my old URI ```/event/path1/{id}/{some_name}?data=data_value```, I just forgot the query string